# Image not displaying correctly using POST messages.json API

Tags: yammer

Posting content to Yammer was a feature we'd successfully implemented a while back but now we are getting reports that the image is broken and showing a grey jigsaw. As well as this we noticed Yammer have changed the layout of posts. We originally were using a profile image, which would now look ridiculous with the layout changing to a squarer rectangle with a large image behind it.

This is the image:

https://cli-cdn.release.workstars.net/jantestvr-3ntsv7ypjestvj0e/employee_images/FzAhje2Cf6gdSKiNkMlEGTZQPvHI5Ju0BxDq7.png

This is url that produces the jigsaw:

https://thumbnails.yammer.com/preview?url=https%3A%2F%2Fcli-cdn.release.workstars.net%2Fjantestvr-3ntsv7ypjestvj0e%2Femployee_images%2FFzAhje2Cf6gdSKiNkMlEGTZQPvHI5Ju0BxDq7.png&signature=RJK%2Fo8yt2vv6DeXXtLrKa5%2BWThnUoXdWAHSIYLPNYqI%3D

Has something changed in the way you need to encode the POST data? I can't get anything other than a jigsaw trying things with the url manually. Also, any way to force the original layout of a full width rectangle with a square image floated inside to the left?

Comment: Just to add to this, it seems it works if I don't use https. The certificate is provisioned though AWS and it is a wildcard certificate. This looks very much like a bug at Yammer's end. When I try to find where to submit a bug it says post to Stackoverflow... Is anyone from Yammer looking at these?

Comment: Can you share the code you were using to post to Yammer? And a screenshot of the post as displayed in Yammer?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/e0MScLFg.png - Image showing https/http version of same image

Comment: https://gist.github.com/hakkor/07dce21ab964e3a6bae03d34aedce1f3 Here's a gist of how I am posting